# Is locate output directory-dependent?

Tags: directory, locate

When I'm in my home directory and type `locate *.cpp` I get hundreds of results.

Using the same command in (for example) `~/../forfun/netstream/`, I see only a few results.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `locate *.cpp` in the shell the shell will first try to expand `*.cpp` to all file names matching that pattern and then call `locate` with this file names as argument.

So if there are any .cpp files in your current directory `locate` will never see the `*.cpp` but only the file names it expands to.

Use

```
locate '*.cpp'
```

if you don't want the shell to try to expand the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`locate` is a database-based finding method. It's damned fast but it's not thorough. I'd suggest using `find` which is comparatively a lot slower, but can do what you're after:

```
find /home/forfun/netstream/ -name '*.cpp'
```

Alternatively if you're happy with the output of locate but just want to trim it down, you can always pipe it through `grep`:

```
locate '*.cpp' | grep 'forfun/netstream'
```